# Compiling DXA 2.2 Java fails with 'Could not find dxa-builder:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT'

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

I tried to install DXA 2.2 Java to Red Hat Linux 8.2.
However, When Executing `prepare.sh`, the Following build Error Occurred:

There is no '2.2.0-SNAPSHOT' on following URL, which is seen in error message.
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/

Why is dxa-builder:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT missing?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'installer'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.sdl.dxa:dxa-builder:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/root/.m2/repository/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
       - file:/root/.m2/repository/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/dxa-builder-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
       - file:/root/.m2/repository/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/dxa-builder-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/dxa-builder-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/dxa-builder-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/dxa-builder-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-builder/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/dxa-builder-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**Update**
In DXA 2.2's known issues,  there is an issue 'Version 2.2.1 required when building a Java web application'

https://docs.sdl.com/784837/743044/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/issue--version-------------2-2-1-required-when-building-a-java-web-application

So I download DXA 2.2.1, and executed following command in dxa-webapp directory.

```
mvn clean package
```

Then, following error occurred.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dxa-webapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sdl.dxa:dxa-webapp:war:2.2.1: Could not find artifact com.sdl.tridion.xo:xo-compatible-client:jar:11.0.0-1057 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

I downloaded `dxa-web-application-java-DXA_2.2.5_Hotfix.tar.gz` from this page.
`https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/releases/tag/DXA_2.2.5_Hotfix`

Then upload it to Linux and it already contains '`dxa-webapp`' directory, so I execute following command
`mvn clean package -P 2.2.5`

I get this command from following page(SDL DXA documentation)
https://docs.sdl.com/792164/548959/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-0/building-your-web-application--java-

Then followng error occurred.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] 'parent.artifactId' is missing. @ line 7, column 13
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.sdl.dxa:dxa-webapp:2.2.5 (/home/ec2-user/dxa-web-application-java-DXA_2.2.5_Hotfix/dxa-webapp/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'parent.artifactId' is missing. @ line 7, column 13
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

I tried `DXA 2.2.4`, it failed by different error.
So I tried `DXA 2.2.3`, then build succeeded and a file `dxa-webapp.war` was generated. I'm not sure what was wrong building 2.2.5 and 2.2.4.

After that, 2.2.3 causes following runtime error.

```
02:31:57.834 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR c.s.w.c.controller.PageController - Exception while processing request for: /
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot detect ViewModel for ViewData MvcDataImpl(controllerAreaName=Framework, controllerName=Page, actionName=Page, areaName=Core, viewName=GeneralPage, regionAreaName=null, regionName=null, routeValues={}, metadata={})
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.model.ViewModelRegistryImpl.getViewModelType(ViewModelRegistryImpl.java:168)
```

**Update**
I editted pom.xml and built DXA 2.2.5 by following command

`mvn clean package -Pcore-module,cid-module -DskipTests -Dcyclonedx.skip=true`

I'm using Linux.There is no following directory in Maven local repository even after executing above command.

`/home/ec2-user/.m2/repository/com/sdl/dxa/modules`

And following error occurred.

```
21-Dec-2020 08:57:49.877 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
        java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
                ... 21 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: className is marked non-null but is null
                at com.sdl.webapp.common.util.InitializationUtils.classForNameIfPresent(InitializationUtils.java:185)
                at com.sdl.dxa.modules.cid.CidWebInitializer.onStartup(CidWebInitializer.java:21)
                at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                ... 27 more
21-Dec-2020 08:57:49.880 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
        java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
                ... 13 more
        Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
                ... 21 more
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
                ... 21 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: className is marked non-null but is null
                at com.sdl.webapp.common.util.InitializationUtils.classForNameIfPresent(InitializationUtils.java:185)
                at com.sdl.dxa.modules.cid.CidWebInitializer.onStartup(CidWebInitializer.java:21)
                at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                ... 27 more
21-Dec-2020 08:57:49.880 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
        Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
                ... 13 more
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
                ... 13 more
        Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
                ... 21 more
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
                ... 21 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: className is marked non-null but is null
                at com.sdl.webapp.common.util.InitializationUtils.classForNameIfPresent(InitializationUtils.java:185)
                at com.sdl.dxa.modules.cid.CidWebInitializer.onStartup(CidWebInitializer.java:21)
                at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                ... 27 more
```

Building with only core module profile, then DXA works.

`mvn clean package -Pcore-module -DskipTests -Dcyclonedx.skip=true`

Comment: there was an issue with the DXA 2.2.0 release that it referenced wrong (internal/not published) versions of some of the CD artifacts, Can you try DXA 2.2.5?

Comment: Building by 'mvn clean package' command for DXA 2.2.5 and DXA 2.2.4 failed, but succeeded for DXA 2.2.3. I wrote result by editing my post. I'm not sure using 2.2.3 is good solution.

Comment: Go far 2.2.3, there are no major changes in 2.2.5, just a few references corrections AFAIK

Comment: 2.2.3 causes runtime error. What is proper way to build and set up DXA?

Comment: Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): 1674: dxa
Choose archetype:
1: remote -> com.sdl.dxa:dxa-webapp-archetype (Example web application for DXA)
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): : 1
Choose com.sdl.dxa:dxa-webapp-archetype version:
21: 2.2.5
Choose a number: 21: 21

Comment: Define value for property 'groupId': com.dxa.sdl
Define value for property 'artifactId': dxawebapp2
Define value for property 'version' 1.0-SNAPSHOT: : 2.2.5
Define value for property 'package' com.dxa.sdl: :
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: com.dxa.sdl
artifactId: dxawebapp2
version: 2.2.5
package: com.dxa.sdl
Y: : Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK - In the DXA Java 2.2.5, A few dependency jars are missing in Maven, and also **XpmRegionConfigImpl** class has an initialization error for **XpmRegionImpl** It was missed in the maven version.

Try following steps to get prepared to use the DXA Java 2.2.5

1. Ensure Java and maven installed as prerequisites as per SDL docs supported versions
2. Run the below command to prepare to download the DXA Java version 2.2.5, adjust the parameters as per your needs.

> mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeArtifactId=dxa-webapp-archetype
> -DarchetypeGroupId=com.sdl.dxa -DarchetypeVersion=2.2.5 -DgroupId=com.sdl.dxa -DartifactId=dxa-webapp -Dversion=2.2.5

3. Verify end of the screen **BUILD SUCCESS** and **dxa-webapp** folder created
   [image]
4. Go to the folder **dxa-webapp** eg. **cd dxa-webapp**
5. Open and update the following dependency to **pom.xml**

```
<!-- existing one just add the version to resolve the XPM issue -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sdl.dxa</groupId>
    <artifactId>dxa-tridion-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Add these missing depedencies -->
<dependency>  
 <groupId>com.sdl.tridion.xo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xo-compatible-client</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.0-1058</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sdl.delivery</groupId>
    <artifactId>udp-common-config-legacy</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.0-1045</version>
</dependency>
```

6. above dependency if you are using 9.0, In case if you are using 9.1+ then refer to this maven links to find out the correct versions

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sdl.tridion.xo/xo-compatible-client
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sdl.delivery/udp-common-config-legacy

7. run this below maven command to build

> mvn clean package -DskipTests -Dcyclonedx.skip=true

8. Verify the end of the screen for **BUILD SUCCESS**

[image]

9. In the Intellij Editor Build you will see this below error message, It means the core-module jar is not downloaded from maven to the local repository.
   You can verify in this location this jar file is exist or not **C:\Users\username.m2\repository\com\sdl\dxa\modules\dxa-module-core\2.2.5\dxa-module-core-2.2.5.jar**
   I had this issue and resolved it by selecting both **core-module** and **cid-module**, And noticed both module jars are downloaded in the local repository, and then I disabled the **cid-module** before build to run the web application in Intellij.

> ERROR c.s.w.c.controller.PageController - Exception while processing
> request for: / java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot detect
> ViewModel for ViewData MvcDataImpl(controllerAreaName=Framework,
> controllerName=Page, actionName=Page, areaName=Core,
> viewName=GeneralPage, regionAreaName=null, regionName=null,
> routeValues={}, metadata={})
> at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.model.ViewModelRegistryImpl.getViewModelType(ViewModelRegistryImpl.java:168)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Indeed build succeed by editing pom.xml, and "Cannot detect ViewModel" error occurred. Then I build DXA with enabling core-module and cid-module but jar files are not created in Maven repository and another error occurred on dxa. I added the command and error message to my question, please see it.

Comment: Ensure core-module folder and jar available in the local repository, remove the cid-module and try run, while building you don't need cid-module unless explicitly you need that module. what I noticed in the profile if we select only core-module sometimes that module does not download from maven, it's downloaded if I select both core and cid modules in the profile, then both modules downloaded from maven to local repository and then I removed the cid-module before building using Intellij.

Comment: Building by selecting only core-module, then DXA works. Even though there is no "module" directory in local repository, following jar file is included in built war file: /WEB-INF/lib/dxa-module-core-2.2.5.jar. I tried building DXA on Windows, then "module" directory was created in local repository, so maven's behavior  might be different between Linux and Windows. I appreciate for your advice. I hope DXA can be installed by only following procedure written in documentation.

Comment: Good to know it works, if that answer helped upvote and accept to close this ticket.

Answer (score 0):

There is latest vesion of dxa-java available on maven 2.2.9, hope that will fix your build related errors.

Comment: FYI DXA Java 2.2.9 all dependencies jars are not in maven