# How to install DXA Java's latest version?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, installation

I want to use DXA Java's latest version.

So I downloaded `DXA 2.2.8` from following page.

https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/releases/tag/DXA_2.2.8_Hotfix

Then I read following manual to know how to install DXA. It say using `prepare.sh` to build DXA, but there is not `prepare.sh` in `DXA 2.2.8`.

https://docs.sdl.com/784837/748553/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/installing-the-------------dxa-java-web-application-for-------------tridion-sites

How can I install `DXA 2.2.8`?

When running generate-from-archetype.cmd, following error occurs.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dxa-webapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sdl.dxa:dxa-webapp:war:2.2.8: Failure to find com.sdl.dxa:dxa-tridion-provider:jar:2.2.8 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.
```

On following URL, there is no directory '2.2.8'. Is the repository correct?

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-tridion-provider/

Regards

Comment: The hotfix can we downloaded seperatly and if you have mvn installed run the generate-from-archetype
https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/releases/tag/DXA_2.2.8_Hotfix
you can generate the webapp.war by running the pom.xml and deploy the webapp on tomcat to access the web application

Comment: When running generate-from-archetype.cmd, an error occurs. It seems dependent jar does not exist in repository .I added the error message to question.

Comment: I am not sure need to cheek please can you try 2.2.9 and update.

Comment: DXA 2.2.9 doesn't exist. 2.2.8 is the latest version.

Comment: i do see 2.2.9 on this https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sdl/dxa/dxa-tridion-provider/ , will have to check and update the post

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, In DXA 2.2.8 and 2.2.9, some of the jars are not pushed to maven, It does not have a  real fix just a refactoring and conflicts. You can go for DXA 2.2.5, I have answered the steps to [prepare DXA 2.2.5 version from Maven](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/21267/compiling-dxa-2-2-java-fails-with-could-not-find-dxa-builder2-2-0-snapshot), I have tested that version with 9.5 OOTB it's working fine as expected.

I have raised this to the engineering team to fix the missing maven jars.

I hope this helps.