# DXA with Java | Cannot detect ViewModel for ViewData MvcDataImpl

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, sdl-tridion, sites-9

I am trying to setup a basic DXA application as steps given here: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/using-and-debugging-dxa-java-with-web-8-5-on-amazon

However, I am facing two issues:

1.)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot detect ViewModel for ViewData MvcDataImpl(controllerAreaName=Framework, controllerName=Entity, actionName=Entity, areaName=GMENEDxaOamFeatures, viewName=Login, regionAreaName=null, regionName=null, routeValues={}, metadata={})
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.model.ViewModelRegistryImpl.getViewModelType(ViewModelRegistryImpl.java:168)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.buildEntityModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:101)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createEntityModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:92)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createEntityModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:79)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.createEntityModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:402)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.lambda$addEntitiesToRegionModels$3(DefaultModelBuilder.java:364)
```

2.) The default pom.xml has dependency versions missing. How to correct this ?
[image]

Comment: PLease let us know what version of DXA java are you trying to install

Comment: I checked the pom.xml of my project. It mentions DXA 2.2.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first issue clearly states that the custom models and views have not been registered with DXA. You'd have to create a class that extends `AbstractModuleInitializer` and register all views and custom entity models. For your setup you should have something like this:

```
@Component
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.sdl.dxa")
public class CustomInitializer extends AbstractModuleInitializer {
    @RegisteredViewModels({ 
        @RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "Login", modelClass = <EntityModelClass>.class)
    })
    @Component
    @ModuleInfo(name = "GMENEDxaOamFeatures Module", areaName = "GMENEDxaOamFeatures", description = "Custom Module")
    public static class GmeneDxaOamFeaturesInitializer extends AbstractModuleInitializer {
        @Override
        protected String getAreaName() {
            return "GMENEDxaOamFeatures";
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the custom views for your module need to be placed in ***src/main/resources/WEB-INF/Views/GMENEDxaOamFeatures***. So the Login.jsp view should go in this folder.

DXA documentation for registering view models: https://docs.sdl.com/784837/551231/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/registering-a-custom-module-in-dxa.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this stack exchange [link](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/21369/how-to-install-dxa-javas-latest-version)  how to install latest java version and some reference on how to build [link](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/21267/compiling-dxa-2-2-java-fails-with-could-not-find-dxa-builder2-2-0-snapshot)